# Receiving a send intent in Ionic via Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, android-intent, ionic4, capacitor

I have an Ionic React project. This comes with Capacitor as bridge. I now want to receive "SEND" intents from other Apps to my Ionic app but I don't find anything suitable in Capacitor. 
The only solution I can think of is creating a custom plugin in Capacitor that will be triggered when I receive the intent in native code. Can anyone suggest a more direct solution?

Comment: I created a plugin for this requirement. You can find it on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/send-intent

Comment: Looking for the same thing. Any luck so far?

Comment: I solved it by creating a new plugin:  [send-intent](http://npmjs.com/package/send-intent)
It should work for text and image data. Feel free to fork. My contact data is on the plugin page if you  are facing issues.

Comment: @CK_One does it support PDF?

Comment: @eozzy it supports any file format by propagating a URI which can then be opened with Capacitor Filesystem. It supports multi-file sharing as well.