# Capacitor app get data passed from another app via intent in Android (and possibly iOS later)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-intent, capacitor

I'm hoping someone could help with an issue I'm having with what would seem a simple task.
I have an Ionic/React project wrapped in Capacitor 3.0 that's being run on Android (and later iOS).
This app should be openable by another app created in native Android/Java a while back.
I have the ability to open my Capacitor app via an intent from the third party app, My issue is that I cannot get the data that the 3rd party app is passing via an intent.

### Breakdown:

I have added code to a button in the third-party Android app. That creates an intent and adds extra data:

### Android app:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myapp.appname");
                if (intent != null) {
                    // We found the activity now start the activity
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("COMPANY_UUID","test 1");
                    intent.putExtra("JOB_NO","JN1234");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    
                } else {
                    
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.myapp.appname"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Then in my capacitor app, I've tried using the Capacitor App plugin to add listeners that I expect to fire when the app is opened.
On the emulator, the intent fire fine, opening my Capacitor app when I click a button, but the listener is not firing. I'm sure I've got something wrong or haven't understood something well enough. Here's code snips for the Ionic/Capacitor end (taken from the Capacitor docs)..

```
import { App, URLOpenListenerEvent } from '@capacitor/app';

const AppUrlListener: React.FC<any> = () => {
    
    let history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
        
        App.addListener('appStateChange', ({ isActive }) => {
            console.log('App state changed. Is active?', isActive);
          });
          

          App.addListener('appRestoredResult', data => {
            console.log('Restored state:', data);
          });
          
          const checkAppLaunchUrl = async () => {
            const m = await App.getLaunchUrl();
            console.log('App opened with URL: ' + m);
        };
        checkAppLaunchUrl();
        
        
        App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
            console.log('App opened with URL: ' + data.url);
          });
          
          App.addListener('appRestoredResult', (data: any) => {
            console.log('Restored state:', data);
          });
    
    }, []);
  
    return null;
  };
  
  export default AppUrlListener;
```

The listeners for state change work fine, logging the values on change. The `getLaunchUrl()` function always returns `undefined` for me.
And the listener `appUrlOpen` never logs.

Ive also added the intent filter as below for the capacitor App:

```
<activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.myapp.appname.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

I've read and tried tuts on adding deep links for my app but again, nothing is logged. In my search for answers, I came across this question [60286364](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286364/receiving-a-send-intent-in-ionic-via-capacitor)
I've also tried the package that the answer describes but I seem to just get errors from this.

If someone could advise on the correct way to tackle allowing an Ionic/Capacitor project to accept and consume data passed from an intent created by another app, it would help loads. the data will be string only. All explanations are appreciated in the hope I can understand the concepts better. Im happy upload more info if required.

Comment: Use this plugin to receive data from other applications: https://github.com/carsten-klaffke/send-intent
You have to do some manual integrations for IOS.

Comment: @ Najam Us Saqib - Thanks for this. This is the stack question I highlighted above. I've added code as suggested from this plugin, but now when running my app I get an error from the plugin:  {message: "No processing needed"}. Do you have any knowledge of this?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/carsten-klaffke/send-intent/issues/19#issuecomment-918219401